# Displaying certain elements from .xml files into a DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, openfiledialog

First off, I'm absolutely new to coding so this might be really trivial, but I couldn't find a solution for this anywhere.

So, I've already got an OpenFileDialog working. I can select the xml files just fine, and it also gives me the path to the selected file. The xml files that I'm talking about contain all sorts of stuff, but I only need to extract two elements from them (zip codes and their corresponding IDs). I've also already created a DataGridView, but I just can't figure out how to make the Grid display my elements. Also, only one xml file will be used at a time.

I'm really sorry about that stupid question, but I've been trying to get this working for hours now.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It may help to post some of your code to show us what problems you've had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to read xml to dataset

```
var xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("File.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
```

and then bind needed values with the DataGridView:

```
YourDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Select(o => new
  {
    Column1 = o.SomeValue,
    Column2 = o.SomeOtherValue
  }).ToList();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, dude! You saved me.